# How to handle multiple radio button on "addTarget" swift 3.0?

Tags: swift3

When I create multiple radio buttons through a `for` loop and using the function `addTarget`, how can I handle multiple radio buttons using `addTarget` by tag or sender in swift 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution change it according to your requirement 
(SWIFT 4)

// create button array to save all button

```
var buttonArray = [UIButton]()

func createButtons(){
    //create 5 buttons
    for i in 1...5 {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: i*55, width: 130, height: 50))
        //set same background for each button
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        // set different ittle for button
        button.setTitle("Button No \(i)", for: .normal)
        // set different tag to differentiate betwwen button
        button.tag = i
        // set same target for each button
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        buttonArray.append(button)
        //add all buttons to main view
        view.addSubview(button)

    }
    // we make first button of different color so that it can act as radio button
    let firstBtn = buttonArray[0]
    firstBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}


@objc func buttonTapped(_ tappedBtn : UIButton){
    // here we get tapped button so from array of button we match the selected one using tag and make it of different color all all other buttons of some different color
    for button in buttonArray {
        if(button.tag == tappedBtn.tag){
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        }else{
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        }
    }

}
```